# Continuity and monotony

Tags: analysis, continuity, monotone-functions

Let $f$ be a monotone increasing function in $[0,1]$. Then there exists an $x$ in this interval, so that $f(x) = x$

How can I solve this? what can I use?

Comment: With the current phrasing, a counter-example would be $$f(x)=x+2$$

Comment: I think you want to assume $f(0)\ge 0$ and $f(1) \le 1$.  Hint: intermediate value theorem for $f(x)-x$.

Comment: This is not true as stated, as $f$ need not even take values in $[0,1]$. Morever, $f$ is not continuous, so even if the previous assumption were made, the map $x\mapsto \mathsf 1_{[0,1/2]}(x)$ doesn't have a fixed point.

Comment: @Math1000 I think OP meant to specify continuity. Especially given that it is in the title.